# QuickFIX/J disabling store messages

Tags: quickfixj

I have a FIX application which receives FIX MarketData messages and sends them to inner applications. I disabled MarketData logging since it's generating extremely large logs but we have the same problem for stores. When I look at a heap dump, I see that there's TreeMap groving continously. Most probably the TreeMap is the one in the FileStore.
What do people do in such cases?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have PersistMessages set to Y? I wonder if that TreeMap is storing state.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class `CustomFileStore` which implements the `MessageStore` interface. Make a constructor taking a `MessageStore` object and store it as a member. Delegate all methods in the `MessageStore` interface to the `MessageStore` member, except for the `set` method. In your implementation of the `set` method filter messages: if it's a MarketData message do nothing, else call `set` on the `MessageStore` member.
2. Create a class `CustomFileStoreFactory` deriving from `FileStoreFactory`, and override the `create` method. In the create method, create a CustomFileStore passing the constructor the return from `super.create` (which would be a `FileStore` object).
3. Pass an instance of `CustomFileStoreFactory` to your `SocketInitiator`.

Note that this is rather hacky and I would not do this myself unless there is no other way (I have never done this myself). If `MessageStore.get` is called on the `CustomFileStore`, it might result in unexpected behaviour (exceptions, or incorrect results). So I would advise against doing this.